# Crowd funded DLC. Is this a viable option for covering the development costs of DLC?

Tags: marketing, fund-raising

I have had this idea floating around in my head for a while now but I am not sure if it will work.

I was looking at the idea of DLC and thought what about if we made some DLC crowdfunded in order to incentivise the players to provide money to cover for the development of it.

Basically the modal I am pondering is this:
DLC is announced and a trailer is shown.
Next the announcement states that a crowdfunding campaign for the development of it has start and people are free to donate money as a backer. Backers get special rewards such as early access, their name included in the credits, etc.
Once the campaign is fully funded development starts immediately and a release date is announced.
Once the DLC is finished and ready for release, it is available for free because all costs have been covered.

The other version is to start development on the DLC right away and run the campaign at the same time. 
If enough people back the project, in addition to the backer rewards, the DLC is released for free.

I am not so sure that this a good idea or not so this is why I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your question may get closed as opinion based, but I like it, so I am going to give my two cents.

I like your idea. But not for the reasons you mentioned.

Crowdfunding the DLC shows whether or not it is worth the development cost. Players have already played the game, and it is less of a gamble for them to purchase the DLC, because they know what to expect. This means the funding you get will have a direct correlation to the DLC sales. If it gets funded, it is worth making. If it doesn't et funded, you had free research to tell you it's no longer a viable product.

I would not make the DLC free to everyone. I would only make it free to those who backed you. In terms of marketing, you get this free focus group with your campaign. You'd be wasting it by saying it's free, because from a money point of view, who cares how many copies it sells if it is free.

So I like your idea of crowd funding it first. If it goes thru, make it (and charge for it). If it doesn't go thru, you've found out is is not worth the development cost any longer.